# How to map values (from a CSV file) with Pandas DataFrame efficiently?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a CSV such as this:

[image]

Where the first column can have gaps, but the second and the third do not have gaps in the middle of the values.

The values of the column `TO_REPLACE` should be replaced with the values in the column `VALUE_TO_COPY` provide that the content of their cells coincide with the cell value of the column `TO_SEARCH`. So the result should be this:

[image]

I have written an script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(
    filepath_or_buffer='mapping_test.csv',
    delimiter=',',
    dtype=str
)

to_replace = df['TO_REPLACE'].copy()
result = df['TO_REPLACE'].copy()

df = df.set_index('TO_SEARCH')
df.dropna(
    how='all',
    inplace=True
)

del df['TO_REPLACE']

for key, value in to_replace.iteritems():
    try:
        result[key] = df.loc[value, 'VALUE_TO_COPY']
    except:
        print('ERROR, not found KEY: {}'.format(key))

result_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'TO_REPLACE': result,
        'VALUE_TO_COPY': list(df['VALUE_TO_COPY']) + [np.nan] * (len(result) - df['VALUE_TO_COPY'].size),
        'TO_SEARCH': list(df.index) + [np.nan] * (len(result) - df['VALUE_TO_COPY'].size),
    }, 
    columns=['TO_REPLACE','VALUE_TO_COPY','TO_SEARCH']  # to preserve the column order
)

result_df.to_csv(
    path_or_buf='mapping_result.csv',
    index=False
)
```

What I do in my code:

1. I read the data from the CSV into a DataFrame
2. I split the DataFrame in two parts. On one hand I store `TO_REPLACE` as a Series and on the other hand a DataFrame with the columns `VALUE_TO_COPY` and `TO_SEARCH`. I use `TO_SEARCH` as the index of this DataFrame.
3. I iterate over the column `TO_REPLACE` in order to find the values in the column `TO_SEARCH`. If the values do not coincide I keep the old value.
4. I build a DataFrame again with the replaced values and I store it into a CSV file.

But it is not very efficient. I need to map many thousands of values very often, that's why I need a more efficient code. Any idea to enhance my code?

Maybe I could use the methods `map` (for Series), `apply` or `applymap` (for DF). At least I have discarded `apply` because it operates on a whole row at a time and `applymap` operates on the whole DataFrame. Maybe the most useful is `map`, but I think it iterates over all the values as I did manually. Another possible option I have considered is the method `replace`, but I have read that `map` is faster.

Comment: Real Python has a great tutorial on speeding up pandas functions: https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/

Comment: You should use `.map`.

Answer (score 1):

[2018-09-03_map_with_pandas.ipynb](https://github.com/trenton3983/stack_overflow/tree/master/complete_solutions)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data/RBefh.csv', dtype=str)
keys = list(df['to_search'].dropna())
values = list(df['value_to_copy'].dropna())
map_values = dict(zip(keys, values))
mapper = df.to_replace.isin(map_values)
df.loc[mapper, 'to_replace'] = df.loc[mapper, 'to_replace'].apply(lambda row: map_values[row])
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
            to_replace       value_to_copy   to_search
0   __import__.value_1  __import__.value_1  2012000401
1   __import__.value_1  __import__.value_2  2012000501
2   __import__.value_1  __import__.value_3  2012000601
3   __import__.value_2  __import__.value_4  2012000603
4   __import__.value_2  __import__.value_5  2012000604
5   __import__.value_2  __import__.value_6  2012000605
6                       __import__.value_7  2012000606
7   __import__.value_2  __import__.value_8  2012000607
8   __import__.value_2  __import__.value_9  2012000608
9   __import__.value_2  __import__.value_10 2012000609
10                      __import__.value_11 2012000610
11  __import__.value_2  __import__.value_12 2012000701
12  __import__.value_2  __import__.value_13 2012000702
13  __import__.value_3      
14  __import__.value_4      
15  __import__.value_5      
16  __import__.value_6      
17  __import__.value_7      
18  __import__.value_8      
19  __import__.value_9      
20  __import__.value_10     
21  __import__.value_11     
22  __import__.value_12     
23  __import__.value_12     
24  __import__.value_12     
25  __import__.value_12     
26  __import__.value_12     
27  __import__.value_12     
28  __import__.value_12     
29  2012999999
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use pandas.

I would read them into a dictionary from a generator.

Use this to access the data:

```
def read_file(fullname):
    with open(fullname) as f:
        for index, line in enumerate(f):
            if index == 0:
                header_line = line
            else:
                yield header_line, line

myFile = read_file(r"Path/To/Your/File")

for header, line in myFile:
    data = dict(zip(header.split(" "), line.split(" ")))
    .....
```

and create a `crosswalk_dict`/several crosswalk dicts that you populate as you loop through the generator.